# mongoose, nodejs limit amount of objects in array

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am looking for a way to limit the amount of objects in a array MongoDB database.
I want to show last 50 events and delete what's old. every x seconds there is a new event, then if amount >= 50 add the latest event but delete the earliest event. Is something like this possible within mongoose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution on how to limit the amount of array items in mongodb

```
$push: {"market": {$each :[market], $slice: -50}}
```